# Prove that this linear operator on the space $\mathbb{R}$[x]$_n$ has the set of eigenvalues $1,a,...,a^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm trying to show that the linear operator $f$ $\mapsto$ $f(ax+b)$ on the space
$\mathbb{R}$[x]$_n$ has the set of eigenvalues $1,a,...,a^n$

I started this question like this
$Tf = \lambda$$f$ $\implies$ $f(ax+b) = \lambda f$

Also since our operator is linear, we have $f(ax+b) = af(x) + f(b)$

Can I put those equations together to somehow get  $af(x) + f(b) = \lambda f \implies \lambda = a$ ?

I think an alternative way to approach this problem would be to find a matrix representation for this transformation but I'm not sure how I would do that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is the space $\mathbb{R}[\mathbf{x}]_n.$

Comment: The polynomials of degree n with real coefficients

Comment: @Nicky_Ay You probably meant hte linear space of real polynomials of degree *less than or equal* $\;n\;$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not try *first* to apply the map on some basis of $\;\Bbb R[x]_n\;$ , say on $\;\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}\;$ ?

$$\begin{align}&T(1)=1&=1\cdot1+0\cdot x+\ldots+0\cdot x^n\\{}\\&Tx=ax+b&=b\cdot 1+a\cdot x+\ldots+0\cdot x^n\\&\ldots\ldots\ldots\\{}\\&Tx^n=(ax+b)^n&=b^n\cdot 1+nb^{n-1}ax+\ldots+a^nx^n\end{align}$$

The corresponding matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&b&\ldots&b^n\\0&a&\ldots&nb^{n-1}a\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\0&0&\ldots&a^n\end{pmatrix}$$

and now you can see this is an upper triangular matrix and what's its main diagonal?